# Identify and remove shortcuts(.lnk) and .vbs files using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file that removes all shortcuts and .vbs from folders. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd firstletterofthepath:
cd path\to\thefolder
for /f %%a in (*.vbs) do del %%a
for /f %%g in (*.lnk) do del %%g
```

this command deletes all .vbs and .lnk files, but only in the current directory. remplace firstletterofthepath by the first letter of the path, like G or E. remplace path/to/folder by the path to folder.
(i cannot test it now so i don't know if it works)

Comment: Why using `pushd` and `cd`? Simply use `cd /D "D:\path\to\the\folder"`; always use `\ `as path separator in Windows `cmd`, never use `/`!

Comment: This not works. The `/d` switch in `for` command process folders, _not_ files! If you don't know if your "solution" works, why you posted it?